# Continuation of one of Dishonored's endings?

Tags: dishonored

As I remember in one of Dishonored's endings,

> Emily dies.

How can this arc be continued in the next game?

Comment: I edited in a spoiler tag for this. I have only played Dishonored once, and this particular ending was spoiled for me just now, so I'd rather avoid others experiencing the same.

Answer (score 2):

As any game with multiple endings, developers usually choose one of the endings to be continued. It would be close to impossible to cover all the endings in one game.